# Hex Twos Complement Arithmetic

Tags: subtraction, hex, twos-complement, base-conversion

I'm trying to do the following problem:

```
 E8B2035D
-FB60528D
----------
```

In which, the integers represented are hex representations of 32-bit two's compliment binary numbers. What is the best approach to solve this problem, and detect overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtraction becomes addition when you use two's complement. So I would take the complement of the second number, then add them:

As you know, the two's complement of a number starts out by turning every 1 into 0 and vice versa (handy rule of thumb: do 15 - number, so F -> 0, E -> 1, D -> 2, etc):

```
FB60528D --> 049FAD72
```

Then add one to the number (in this case, `2 + 1 = 3`, and there is no carry):

```
049FAD73 -- the two's complement of FB60528D
```

Now we add the numbers, using conventional rules of addition:

```
E8B2035D
049FAD73 +
----------

D + 3 = 10 : write 0, carry 1
1 + 5 + 7  : write D, carry 0
3 + D = 10 : write 0, carry 1
1 + 0 + A  : write B, carry 0
2 + F      : write 1, carry 1 
1 + B + 9  : write 5, carry 1
1 + 8 + 4  : write D, carry 0
E + 0      : write E
```

The final result (still in two's complement) is

```
ED51B0D0
```

You would detect overflow if the last calculation resulted in a carry (a number > `F`).